# convert a word documents to HTML with embedded images by TIKA

Tags: java, c#, apache-tika

I'm new in TIKA. I try to convert Microsoft word documents to HTML by using Tika. I'm using TikaOnDotNet wrapper to used TIKA on .Net framework. My conversion code is like following:

```
        byte[] file = Files.toByteArray(new File(@"myPath\document.doc"));
        AutoDetectParser tikaParser = new AutoDetectParser();

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        handler.setResult(new StreamResult(output));

        ExpandedTitleContentHandler handler1 = new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(handler);

        tikaParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(file), handler1, new Metadata());


        File ofile = new File(@"C:\toHtml\text.html");
        ofile.createNewFile();
        DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(ofile));
        output.writeTo(stream);
```

everything working well except the embedded images. The generated HTML contains image tag like:

```
<img src="embedded:image2.wmf" alt="image2.wmf"/>
```

but the image source does not exists. Please advise me

Comment: Did you forget to set a suitable [EmbeddedDocumentExtractor](http://tika.apache.org/1.13/api/org/apache/tika/extractor/EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.html) on the `ParseContext` to specify what resources to save and where too?

Comment: @Gagravarr Could you provide me an example? I think this is the main reason.

Comment: The `TikaCLI` has one, eg [this bit in Git](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-app/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/cli/TikaCLI.java#L1004)

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, I manage to extract the images from doc, but  in HTMl how can I change src for each extracted images ?

Comment: You'd need your own custom SAX handler for that too. Best example I can think of [is this Alfresco class which uses Tika to turn Word docs into HTML + images both saved in the Alfresco repository](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/rendition/executer/HTMLRenderingEngine.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits goes to @Gagravarr.

please note that this is a simple implementation of code, the original codes are available in comment of the questions.

This implementation is based on TikaOnDotNet wrapper.....

```
public class DocToHtml
{

    private TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    public void Convert()
    {

        byte[] file = Files.toByteArray(new File(@"filename.doc"));
        AutoDetectParser tikaParser = new AutoDetectParser();

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        var inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file);
        //           ToHTMLContentHandler handler = new ToHTMLContentHandler();
        var metaData = new Metadata();
        EncodingDetector encodingDetector = new UniversalEncodingDetector();
        var encode = encodingDetector.detect(inputStream, metaData) ?? new UTF_32();
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encode.toString());
        handler.setResult(new StreamResult(output));

        ContentHandler imageRewriting = new ImageRewritingContentHandler(handler); 

        //  ExpandedTitleContentHandler handler1 = new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(handler);
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        context.set(typeof(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor), new FileEmbeddedDocumentEtractor());

        tikaParser.parse(inputStream, imageRewriting, new Metadata(), context);


        byte[] array =  output.toByteArray();

       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\toHtml\text.html", array);

    }


    private class ImageRewritingContentHandler : ContentHandlerDecorator
    {
        public ImageRewritingContentHandler(ContentHandler handler) : base(handler)
        {
        }

        public override void startElement(string uri, string localName, string name, Attributes origAttrs)
        {
            if ("img".Equals(localName))
            {
                AttributesImpl attrs;
                if (origAttrs is AttributesImpl)
                    attrs = (AttributesImpl)origAttrs;
                else
                    attrs = new AttributesImpl(origAttrs);



                for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    if ("src".Equals(attrs.getLocalName(i)))
                    {
                        String src = attrs.getValue(i);
                        if (src.StartsWith("embedded:"))
                        {
                            var newSrc = src.Replace("embedded:", @"images\");

                            attrs.setValue(i, newSrc);
                        }
                    }
                }
                attrs.addAttribute(null, "width", "width","width", "100px");
                base.startElement(uri, localName, name, attrs);
            }
            else
                base.startElement(uri, localName, name, origAttrs);
        }
    }

    private class FileEmbeddedDocumentEtractor : EmbeddedDocumentExtractor
    {
        private int count = 0;
        public bool shouldParseEmbedded(Metadata m)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void parseEmbedded(InputStream inputStream, ContentHandler contentHandler, Metadata metadata, bool outputHtml)
        {
            Detector detector = new DefaultDetector();
            string name = metadata.get("resourceName");
            MediaType contentType = detector.detect(inputStream, metadata);
            if (contentType.getType() != "image") return;
            var embeddedFile = name;
            File outputFile = new File(@"C:\toHtml\images", embeddedFile);
            try
            {
                using (FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile))
                {
                    var tin = inputStream as TikaInputStream;
                    if (tin != null)
                    {
                        if (tin.getOpenContainer() != null && tin.getOpenContainer() is DirectoryEntry)
                        {
                            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

                            fs.writeFilesystem(os);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, os);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```